# iOS - parse xml DATASET

Tags: objective-c, soap, xml-parsing, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

This is my XML data that I need to parse

```
 <GetMessagesResult>
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
       <Table>
          <Date>21:52:59</Date>
          <Message>ABC</Message>
          <GroupName>ALL</GroupName>
       </Table>
       <Table>
          <Date>11:23:27</Date>
          <Message>DEF</Message>
          <GroupName>ALL</GroupName>
       </Table>
   </NewDataSet>
 </GetMessagesResult>
```

This is my SCMessages.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SCMessages : NSObject
{
    NSDate *Date;
    NSString *Message;
    NSString *GroupName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *Date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Message;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *GroupName;
```

and this is my SCMessages.m file

```
#import "SCMessages.h"
@implementation SCMessages
@synthesize Date;
@synthesize Message,GroupName;
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [Date release];
    [Message release];
    [GroupName release];
}
@end
```

I used below code to parse the data using `NSXMLParser` delegate methods

```
#pragma mark - NSXMLParser Delegate

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetMessagesResult"])
    {
        if(!soapResults)
        soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        recordResults = TRUE;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Table"]) {
        //Initialize the message.
        aMessage = [[SCMessages alloc] init];
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if( recordResults )
        [soapResults appendString: string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Table"]) {
        [messages addObject:aMessage];
            NSLog(@"MESSAGES COUNT: %d",messages.count);
            NSLog(@"MESSAGE: %@",aMessage);
        [aMessage release];
        aMessage = nil;
    }
    // as this is the last element
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"])
    {
        recordResults = FALSE;
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM** *I am not getting the desired message object with Date, Meesage & GroupName.*

I put `NSLog` to print them but I always get null value. The weird thing is message array gets allocated memory & also elements gets added to array as I can see message array count in `NSLog` but the array element has data as null value.

I am parsing the XML data received in SOAP response in NSURLConnection delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading`

```
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"theXML: \n%@",theXML);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your values in `aMessage`. You have added particular object to array but you forgot to store data in that object of SCMessages class.You can also check while debug that you are getting value in `aMessage` object.

You need to store value like this in this `didEndElement` method.

```
 [aMessage setValue: soapResults forKey:elementName];
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your didEnd method is missing code to store the accumulated string into a property. You need an ivar for the current SCMessage object.

Append text content to a mutable string ivar. Then on closing an element you have to decide which property to set on SCMessage. You probably have to parse the date into an NSDate.

Comment: I couldnt understand :( Can u pls elaborate in terms of code!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to write your code for you. Also I am on my iPad. You are missing a place where you would put the found characters into the properties. And for each table element start you encounter you need to create a new message object.